# New to SOLR, some installation help needed

Tags: java, mysql, database, apache, solr

I have downloaded a SOLR release, and sun JDK. I have installed SUN now...
I am using wampserver on my computer, to test SOLR out first, and learn how it works...

I don't understand how to install it and use it though... I am completely new to it and java as well, so I need some help on this one...

After downloading it, and unzipping it to a folder, what do I need to do next?

Also, what is a servlet container?

I have all my files (the website) in this folder: localhost/SV/

The tutorial SOLR provides isn't written in detail, and I think thats what I would need.

Do I need to do any changes to any files on my virtual (Wampserver) server?

Let me know if you need more input from me and I will update this Q...

Comment: This should probably go on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using WAMP.. I'm in the same boat (well using windows) as you and also found it difficult.. So i created a guide once i'd finally figured it out. This guide is using apache-tomcat though.

You can find it here:

http://www.craftyfella.com/2009/12/installing-solr-14-on-windows-xp-step.html

Let me know if it helps.. as it was created just for us windoze people :)

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes you can just use the included Jetty. Go to the directory where **start.jar** is located and run `java -jar start.jar`, then point your browser to `http://localhost:8983/solr`. There you will see an admin console where you can issue queries against the index, but it will be initially empty. See the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html) for more details.

For production use you'll have to use a properly configured and tuned container. Start [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall), you will find detailed instructions for each container.

Web containers provide the runtime environment to run web applications on a web server. For more information on web containers, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container
- http://www.service-architecture.com/application-servers/articles/j2ee_web_server_or_container.html

or ask another, more specific question on stackoverflow about this.

Comment: ok, but how do I run "scripts" as they referr to in the tutorial? Example post.sh which I should run if I want to add indexes, how do I run this file? Thanks again

Comment: Please read the tutorial. It uses post.jar, **not** post.sh to add documents to the index.